# Prevent R abbreviating single string output in console?

Tags: r, windows

If I run

```
Sys.getenv(c("R_HOME"))
```

I see

```
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0"
```

Which is an abbreviation of the full path.

How can I return the full string (in this case, the full path)?

Comment: See `?normalizePath`. Also, `R.home()` is a short form of your question command.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I wanted to post `normalizePath` as the answer but you replied before me. This is the answer, could you post it ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Actually, no, it's probably better if you post it. I'm on Ubuntu and cannot test and present an input/output example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `normalizePath`:

```
> x <- shortPathName("C:/Program Files (x86)/")
> x
[1] "C:\\PROGRA~2\\"
> normalizePath(x)
[1] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\"
```